# Is there any way to add range in 'Date' dimension for saiku-analytics 2.3 plugin for pentaho-bi-server 4.5?

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku, olap4j

I am using Pentaho bi-server for data analytics purpose with saiku plugin as its community edition, It is working fine with normal dimensions but when i want feature like date range or dates greater than some specific date, there is no such functionality there. I tried editing MDX query and store them but it didn't work.

Actually What I want is to pass parameters to a stored saiku files like to get records between two dates...It can be done by changing this in datasource SQL query but it will be rigid way. All time I have to change there and refresh the cache.

Other way I found is there default filter but in this case i have to select each date what i have to use for analytics...